# Triangulated Toruses in Sketch

Tags: graphics, diagrams, 3d

I want to be able to use sketch to generate an image like [this](http://img.springerimages.com/Images/SpringerBooks/BSE=4318/BOK=978-1-4419-7236-1/CHP=5_10.1007-978-1-4419-7236-1_5/MediaObjects/WATER_187616_1_En_5_Fig1_HTML.jpg):

[image]

I am able to get the torus okay using nested sweeps as demonstrated in the [tutorial](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/sketch.html#Nested-sweeps), but my attempts to draw the diagonals using rotations in a sweep distorted the torus in ways I didn't intend. How can I generate this image?

Comment: Can you show the code you got so far?

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic: while Sketch can export generated images to (La)TeX, how to make images with Sketch is not in this site's scope.

Comment: Not of the best questions out there, but Sketch maybe considered a good TeX-friend. Are questions on Asymptote also off-topic, then?